# How can I calculate powers of 2 using left shift operator for large powers?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate powers of two without using Math.Pow because i want to avoid using double.  So I need a whole integer value.  I thought that I could just use the left shift operator but when my power goes past 30, it gives a negative number for power 31, and 1 for powers larger than 31.

My method looks like

```
    public static long TwoPowX(int power)
    {
        return (1 << power);
    }
```

Any ideas? Or alternative method?

EDIT:
I need to go as high as power 96 maybe more.

2^96 = 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, instead of long (Int64) which goes to maximum of power 63, I used BigInteger from System.Numerics

```
    public static BigInteger TwoPowX(int power)
    {
        return ((BigInteger)1 << power);
    }
```

and then usage

```
    BigInteger test = Utility.TwoPowX(96);
```

yields the correct value for powers greater than 63 (in this example - power of 96)

```
{79228162514264337593543950336}
```

Answer (score 6):

The literal `1` is an int, so the whole expression `(1 << power)` will also be evaluated as int and overflow before being converted to long. Use `1L` instead.

```
public static long TwoPowX(int power)
{
    return (1L << power);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the maximum power? 
Since int consists of 32 bits (31 bits for positive numbers) you get an overflow.

You can use long instead,  but then keep in mind the maximum will be a power of 63.

```
return (long) 1 << power;
```

Comment: And how would he do that?

Comment: that is a good point, I'm going as high as power 96, I'll add that to my question